# Escaping leading number classnames for querySelector in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to run this:

```
document.querySelector('#js-Overlay .3dObject').classList.toggle('flipY');
```

I do realise you have to escape it, but the following isn't working:

```
document.querySelector('#js-Overlay \\.3dObject').classList.toggle('flipY');
```

Any idea how I can successfully escape the leading number classname?

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="js-Overlay">
    <div class="3dObject"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an illegal class name.

The [Selectors Level 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#class-html) says:

> The class selector is given as a full stop (. U+002E) immediately followed by an identifier

How do we define an identifier? Well, that page links to the CSS 2.1 specification.

From the [CSS2.1 syntax specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and ISO 10646 characters `U+00A0` and higher, plus the hyphen (`-`) and the underscore (`_`); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

The class is therefore not legal, and you shouldn't expect to <s>have trouble finding it</s> be able to find it with `querySelector`.

(That said, `getElementsByClassName('3dObject')` [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/T53Z9/1/).)

Comment: _"The class is therefore not legal, and you shouldn't expect **not?** to have trouble finding it with querySelector"_

Comment: @gdoron Ah yes, the old `!!` problem.